# Sync highlight pdf between ubuntu and android

Tags: android, pdf

I want to know if there is a way to synchronize a pdf with highlights between my ubuntu desktop and my android tablet.

I know there are several ways to do it in Mac, but I am not aware of one possibility in linux-ubuntu.

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could easily do this with [Ubuntu One](http://one.ubuntu.com).  Save your PDF to your Ubuntu One folder.    Then go and get the Ubuntu One Android app, which should allow you to view your PDF.  Any changes you make to it will then be sync'd through the cloud.

Comment: but I can edit, i.e. highlight the pdf again in my tablet?